# Qt + OpenCV + eclipse (on windows)

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, opencv

can anyone please help me with a tutorial for integrating Qt and OpenCV on eclipse IDE? (windows).

Qt works just fine, OpenCV works just fine,
but together - no good..

I'm losing my mind here..

Thanks!

Comment: You may wish to detail what "no good" encompasses.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried OpenCV using [QT Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/developer-tools/developer-tools#qt-tools-at-a) ?

and another answer which gives information on using [third party libraries in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647698/qt-add-path-for-3rd-party-header-and-libraries).